# Moving android adView code from Library layout file to the advert based app layout

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I have an android app which is marked as library and two more apps (trial version and full) which are essentially using the library and only have a package name and little bit of code in there like one has to have adverts and others don't etc.

So all (99.9%) of the code lives in library whichever app is used.

The following is the main Layout xml file of the LIBRARY APPLICATION. The adView element is also present in this file and I would like only the adview Element to be somehow in the trial app's layout without duplicating the entire layout of the library.Trial app has no layout right now it just has the libray as dependency.

How can I achieve moving the adView element code from the layout below to the relevant app who right now has no layout.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

         .... more code here
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/info_window"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
         ...more code here

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Edit: Just to add little bit more detail the app has minApi 9 and does not use support library etc

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't remove the AdView from your library XML. I would instead use code in your apps to only load and show the banner ads in the relevant app.